# This won't run without Google Play services,which are not supported by your device

Tags: android

При включении приложения на девайсах ниже 19 апи выпадает сообщение:
This won't run without Google Play services,which are not supported by your device.
Установлена минимальная версия 16.

Comment: На эмуляторе выпадает ошибка или на реальных устройствах?

Comment: да. Проблема в эмуляторе?

Comment: На эмуляторе установлена Google Play Service старых версий. На устройстве google play service всегда должно быть выше версии чем вы используете в своем приложении. Проверьте на реальном устройстве тоже

Comment: Уже проверил. Вы правы дело в эмуляторе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всей видимости в проверяли на эмуляторе. Там установлена Google Play Service старых версий. На устройствах google play service всегда должно быть выше версии чем вы используете в своем приложении. Поэтому проверяйте на реальном устройстве.